# React context typings coming back as 'any' by typescript

Tags: reactjs, typescript, react-context

Given the following code (simplified):

```
type TestContextType = {
    test: number
}

const context = React.createContext<TestContextType>({
    test: 0
})

const used = React.useContext(context)
```

The typings for 'context' and 'used' are set to 'any':

[image]

I've tried restarting ts server, restarting the IDE, computer, etc with no luck. ALl other typings are working as expected.

Comment: Can you give any more details about your IDE and setup? The code you gave works in [CodeSandbox](https://codesandbox.io/s/spring-microservice-hhwcxd?file=/src/App.tsx), at least.

Comment: you must be using old typescript version

Answer (score 2):

the code you mentioned should works fine
please find my tsconfig.josn

```
{
  "compilerOptions": {
    "target": "es5",
    "lib": [
      "dom",
      "dom.iterable",
      "esnext"
    ],
    "allowJs": true,
    "skipLibCheck": true,
    "esModuleInterop": true,
    "allowSyntheticDefaultImports": true,
    "strict": true,
    "forceConsistentCasingInFileNames": true,
    "noFallthroughCasesInSwitch": true,
    "module": "esnext",
    "moduleResolution": "node",
    "resolveJsonModule": true,
    "isolatedModules": true,
    "noEmit": true,
    "jsx": "react-jsx",
    "baseUrl": "src"
  },
    "include": ["src/**/*"],
    "exclude": ["node_modules"]
}
```

and I installed typescript

```
  "typescript": "^4.9.5",
```

also make sure you end your file with `.ts`